# Search shows wrong url

Tags: 2013, search, alternate-access-mapping

I have a web application that i extended. One of the these sites is used to crawl the other is for anonymous access. My issue is that the anonymous access site, has the crawled items for the one that is being crawled. How do i change it so the one that is being crawled still has the url of the crawled site yet the anonymous site has its own url.
Web app A - https://test.co.uk
web app B - http://testing.co.uk

Web app A was extended to include Web App B. Web app A is being crawled by Search. However when i search in Web app B the urls are of Web app A when i need them to be web app B

Comment: Can you please more explain about the issue?

Comment: In your content source are you only crawling the default zone or are you crawling both the default and extended zone?